# How can I check whether a variable has a buffer-local value in Emacs `org-mode`?

Tags: variables, emacs, documentation, org-mode

**How can I check that the value for `org-drill-cram-hours` has been set in the buffer (emacs-org-mode)?**

```
# Local Variables:
# org-drill-cram-hours: 0
# org-drill-hide-item-headings-p: t
# End:
```

1. I have the above in the **TOP OF MY** org-mode buffer.
2. I re-opened the file using `C-x C-v` after adding these values.
3. I don't think the local variable value is set, cause when I run `org-drill-cram`, it does not do what is expected (go over all the buffer points i.e.).

I want to check the local value set for `org-drill-cram-hours`, but when I do `C-h v org-drill-cram-hours`, I don't see the buffer-local value.

```
org-drill-cram-hours is a variable defined in ‘org-drill.el’.
Its value is 12
```

What am I missing? I don't want to use `setq` or `C-h v variable` to SET the value.

P.S.
(However if I change the variable value through `C-h v var`, then `org-drill-cram` works as expected.)

Comment: Just use `C-h v org-drill-cram-hours` *with that buffer current*. That tells you the buffer-local value (if any) and the global value. If it doesn't specify a buffer-local value then you haven't defined one for that buffer.

Comment: I added it to the bottom of the page and then `C-x C-v`. I see 2 values now when I do `C-h v org-drill-cram-hours`. Thank You. :)

Comment: Great. I've posted my comment as an answer, in that case. (Comments can be deleted at any time.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `C-h v org-drill-cram-hours` *with that buffer current*.

That tells you (1) the buffer-local value, if there is one, and (2) the global value. If it doesn't specify a buffer-local value then you haven't defined one for that buffer.

---

For example, if buffer `foobar` has a buffer-local value then `C-h v org-drill-cram-hours` shows this:

```
org-drill-cram-hours is a variable defined in `org-drill.el'.
Its value is 0
Original value was 12
Local in buffer foobar; global value is 12
```

Comment: In addition to this: I needed to write the local variable lines at the bottom of the page and not the TOP!

Comment: Specifically, it needs to be in the last page (or last 3000 chars) of the file.  So in a small file, the top would be acceptable.  It's normal and expected to put these very near the end, though.